# cannot install netbeans module because compatibility (some plugins require plugin to be installed)

Tags: netbeans, module, compatibility

I developed a netbeans module on Netbeans IDE 7.3.1.
When i tried to install it on other computer with Netbeans IDE 7.3, i got this error:

Some plugins require plugin Settings API to be installed.
The plugin Settings API is requested in version >= 1.38.2 but only 1.38.1 was found.

Some plugins require plugin Utilities API to be installed.
The plugin Utilities API is requested in version >= 8.29.3 but only 8.29.2 was found.

There is something that i can do to fix this error? What should i do?

I want to avoid to develop the same module again, but on Netbeans IDE 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was pretty easy to fix, but **I don't think this is how it should be done (the NB way)**. It would be better to be able to specify a *minimum version*, but I've yet to find out how.

Anyway...

Go to your module's project descriptor, in `nbproject\project.xml`.

There, you'll find the version for each of your module's dependencies.

Find the Setting API module and change the version from 1.38.2 to 1.38.1.
Find the Utilities API module and change the version from 8.29.3 to 8.29.2.

Re-build the project.

*You may need to do this several times for some other dependencies.*

Now your module should work with NB 7.3+.